# SwitchCompat footer view

Tags: android, switchcompat

I tried to add a footer view to my navigation drawer list containing a SwitchCompat. On pre-KitKat devices, the footer doesn't show up at all - following the debugger steps, the view inflates and is added as a footer, but is not drawn at all.

Moving the view into a fragment view produces no issues - it draws properly and behaves as you would expect.

Does anyone know why SwitchCompat doesn't play nicely with ListView footers?

Comment: As a side note, I've lodged a bug report with the Android team.